# Top de rham degree of the total space of a vector bundle

Tags: homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory, vector-bundles, de-rham-cohomology

By homotopy invariance of the de Rham cohomology and the fact that the total space of every smooth vector bundle $E\to M$ is homotopy equivalent to its base space $M$ ($M$ is a smooth manifold), we have the following isomorphism of singular cohomologies:
$$H^p(E, \mathbb C)\cong H^p(M, \mathbb C)$$
for every $p=0,.., \max\{\dim E, \dim M\}$. Does this mean that the top singular cohomology degree of the tangent bundle $TM$ is $\dim M$? Meaning,

$$H^p(TM, \mathbb C)=0$$
for all $p>\dim M$?

Comment: Yes this is true. This gives a cute proof (for manifolds without boundary) that TM is not compact: it's top (2nth) cohomology vanishes (which is false for compact orientable manifolds).

Comment: Thank you, David!  What do you mean that the second top singular cohomology of TM vanishes? Could you elaborate on that? Do you mean that $H^{\dim TM}(TM, \mathbb C)=0$ and that this is false for compact orientable manifolds?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean, because $2n = \dim TM$ if $n = \dim M$.